# PostGIS create read only user for QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am having issues reading spatial tables in QGIS with a select-only "reader" user.  I can create the reader user to access regular postgres tables like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test TO reader;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA test
    GRANT SELECT ON TABLES
    TO reader;
```

What do I need to add to allow the user to view tables in QGIS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql

Comment: I used that but forgot a part, how embarrassing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL in my question only works for tables created after the statement, to alter already created tables use:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA test TO reader;
```